# Typescript: How to convert a function expression to class

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class

I would like to have this code in typescript

```
import StandardError from 'standard-error';
import Http from 'http';

function StkError(code, msg) {

  StandardError.call(
    this,
    { body: msg.body, params: msg.request.params, query: msg.request.query } || Http.STATUS_CODES[code],
    {
      code,
    },
  );
}

StkError.prototype = Object.create(StandardError.prototype, {
  constructor: { value: StkError, configurable: true, writable: true },
});


export default StkError;
```

y tried with this

```
   class StkError extends StandardError {
      constructor(code: any, msg: any) {
        super(msg, code);
      }
    }
```

but i don't know how to integrate the function `call`

i'm triyng to use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/standard-error) with typescript.

im new with typescript, thank you for your help

Comment: You don't use `call` at all. If you want to pass these objects as arguments to `StandardError`, write them as arguments of the `super` call.

Comment: But really I would recommend to use a different library that explicitly supports (and documents the use of) ES6 `class` syntax. There are many.